# VS2013 git with ext2fsd

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, ext3

VS2013 has built in git support. Working with repos on C:\ (NTFS) is fine. However, working with repos on F:\ (EXT3 via ext2fsd) yields this error:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Invalid (Error). 
> Failed to open directory 'F:/aolney/research_projects/boredom/code/turk/SilverTurk/.git/objects/pack/'

This error has previously been reported for deeply nested folders, but I also tried creating a new repo at F:/aolney/repos and it failed with the same error.

In all other respects, ext2fsd is working great. Ext2fsd 0.52 is installed. Machine is Win 8.1 Pro, x64. Git version is 1.8.3. VS2013 version is ultimate update 2.

The above error occurred when trying to check in to a new local repository, but the same error (with different path) occurs for all git operations I've tried.

I can use the git gui tool on the F:/ drive (EXT3) which makes me think this is some weird interaction between VS2013, git, and ext2fsd

Comment: I can assure you that this has never been tested.  I'll see if I can take a look this week.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this

Comment: Here's an update that might add some more clarity. If I have VS2013 open from an NTFS drive, with a working git repo *and* I have a VS2013 open from the EXT3 drive, if I then try to commit from the NTFS, it fails with this message: An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Invalid (Error).
Failed to rename lockfile to 'C:/Users/aolne_000/Desktop/CLASS5-VSO/.git/refs/heads/master': Access is denied. *UNTIL* I close the EXT3 VS2013, and then it works fine.

Comment: Since this still hasn't moved forward, I've come up with a pretty good workaround that has VS integration. Simply install the Git Source Control Provider here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c and follow the documentation for switching from the MS provider to the vsix provider